# unable to import OVA to GCP

Tags: import

Uploaded the OVA file to GCP storage bucket. Then I have tried to import the appliance into GCP using the following commands:

```
gcloud config set compute/zone us-east4-a
gcloud config set project demos-sed-security-lategan
gcloud compute instances import dlp-ova    --source-uri=gs://dlp-ova/SYMCDLPMGR15.7MP1v2GCP.ova
```

The error I am getting:

> Logs are available at [https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/93758484-6109-43f7-a366-828a7e1c63b8?project=525410428383].
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.import)
>
> HTTPError 403:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <Error>
>   <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
>   <Message>Access denied.</Message>
>   <Details>richard.tadros@broadcom.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.</Details>
> </Error>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to check your cloud bucket is in the same project as the compute instance.

In this case the "dlp-ova" bucket should be part of the "demos-sed-security-lategan" project. Otherwise you may need to assign additional access permissions as per https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/import-ovf-files#import-across-projects